# perl extract and parse

Tags: xml, perl

I am new to Perl and trying to figure out the issue with the script.

2.what changes I can make to accept multiple XML one by one through command line?

3.How to direct o/p of  function to text file?

4.How to direct o/p of  function to i/p to other function as an argument?

Comment: I suggest to restore the question as it had been, at least most of it.  The example of what you were doing made most things clear, and it was well formed and generally useful for others. What stayed, without any code, doesn't make much sense. For one thing, it invalidates both answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your module file, the `package` statement and the `use` statement should all be spelled the same, and should all begin with a capital letter. It looks like your module file should be called `NVD.pm`

1. You have declared `@vuln`, not `%vuln`
2. You can *add* values to a hash by writing this

   ```
   my %vuln;

   for ( @ARGV ) {
       %vuln = ( %vuln, NVD::extract($_) );
   }
   ```

   That will aggregate the results for all files mentioned on the command line
3. It depends what you want. The result of `extract` is a hash structure, so you will need to format the data somehow. In general you can write

   ```
   open my $fh, '>', 'output.txt' or die $!;

   print ... extracting data from `%vuln` as required

   close $fh;
   ```
4. By writing simply

   ```
   other_function(NVD::extract($_))
   ```

   or possibly

   ```
   my %vuln = NVD::extract($_);
   other_function(%vuln);
   ```